# Game Algorithm for Removing Subsets [HW/Study]

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

We have been given a problem which I have reduced to the following :
You are given a Binary number with all ones (eg 11111) and a set of binary numbers of the same length (00101, 10000, 01100, 00100, 11100).
There are two players A & B. At each turn a player can subtract from the main binary number(11111) any one of the smaller numbers such that the binary AND of the 2 is the smaller number. then the next player can subtract from the resultant, and so on. The player which cannot subtract anymore, loses.
eg.

```
   A         B       
 11111     11010   // Now A cannot subtract 
-00101    -10000   // anymore in the next turn. 
-------   ------   // So B wins the game.
 11010     01010
-------   ------
```

If both the players play optimally (making the best choice for their victory), I have to find out which player wins for the given combination of Binary numbers.

I have tried an O(n^2) approach, but is there a faster way ?

Edit:
O(n^2) : where n is the number of states. For a binary number of length 6 (111111) there will be 2^6 states possible. so my complexity being O((2^6)^2).

Edit:
My Code that generates all possible States:

```
void makeAllStates() /* Bottom Up Approach. Starting from 00000 and going to 11111 */
{
    // bool states[i] : True if state[i] is a winning position.
    // bool isWord[i] : True if the given state matches a smaller number. (eg. If the main number has been reduced to 10110 and there is a smaller number 10110, then isWord[i] is true.
    // bool visited[i] : True If the given state has been visited  
    // int statecount : Total number of states
    int temp;
    for(int xx=1;xx<stateCount;xx++)
    {
        for(int yy=1;yy<stateCount;yy++)
        {
            if(xx&yy)
                continue;
            if(!(isWord[xx] || isWord[yy]))
                continue;
            if(!visited[yy])
                continue;
            temp = xx^yy;
            if(isWord[temp])
                continue;
            if(states[temp])
                continue;
            if(isWord[xx] && isWord[yy])
                states[temp] = false;
            else
            {
                if(isWord[xx])
                    states[temp] = !states[yy];
                else
                    states[temp] = !states[xx];
            }
            visited[temp] = true;
            if(temp == stateCount-1 && states[temp])
            {
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the subtraction can only happen when the AND is the smaller number, it's equivalent to XOR and to ANDing with the complement of the smaller number. I'm not sure if that helps, but it's a little simpler.

Comment: This sounds similar to Nim <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim>, there a bit of the theory is explored.

Comment: @harold : Infact it can be taken as an XOR all together and verified using ANDing.

Comment: @vonbrand : Yes. But I am unable to figure our any relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it will help you (you told about O(n^2) approach, but didn't say what N means). Try the generic approach for impartial games (Sprague-Grundy theory):

- the position in game is your main number
- Find all "loosing" positions (such positions that you can't subtract anything anymore)
- for all "loosing" positions x : Grundy function g(x) = 0;
- Then, if you want to calculate the grundy function for position y: find all positions x_1...x_k such that you can make a turn from position y to position x_i. g(y) = mex(g(x_1),...,g(x_k)). "mex" is "minimal excludant" - the smallest non-negative integer of all except g(x_1),...,g(x_k). For example, mex(2, 3, 4) = 0, mex(0, 1, 2, 5) = 3, mex(0, 1) = 2, etc.

Note that you can recursively consider every game position, and you will consider position x once (while calculating g(x)), so this algorithm is <strike>linear by the number of possible positions.</strike> linear by the number of possible turns between positions, i.e. O(N*K) where N is the number of states and K is the size of set of smaller numbers (with which you can make turns in your game)

If g(START_POSITION) = 0, then start position is the loosing position, and the first player looses (every turn leads to a winning position). If g(START_POSITION) > 0 then start position is the winning position (there exists a turn to position x such that g(x) = 0), so the first player wins.

Sorry about poor english, and hope it will be helpful

Comment: Sorry about the missing info. Updated now. Thats the same approach that gave me O(n^2) time complexity. Will try to reduce it to O(n) using your approach.

Comment: Couldnt reduce the complexity to O(n), but using your approach , reduced the number of calls to a great extent.
Adding my Final Code below!

Comment: It's my bad, sorry, I thought it's linear by the number of states, but it's complexity equals the complexity of the depth-first-search in position graph, i.e. O(N*K) there N - number of states, K - size of the set of smaller numbers. Just edited my answer.

Comment: By the way, one of the key points in sprague-grundy theory is, that if  you generalize this game as: the position is set of main numbers x_1, x_2, ..., x_k and each time you can make turn with choosing the main number x_i and then operate with it, then G(x_1,x_2,...,x_k) is just g(x_1) XOR g(x_1) XOR ... XOR g(x_k), where XOR is calculated bitwise with integer g(x_j) grundy functions. Every impartial game (winner or looser is determined by the initial position) can be reduced to NIM game.

Answer (score 0):

Based on K.Bulatov's input, here is the final Code with a time Complexity of O(n^2) in the worst case. After pruning , the number of calls have been reduced to a great extent.
The main Function is the following :

```
//state : The state for which grundy number is being queried.
//visited[i] : If the grundy number of the state has already been calculated.
//wordStates[] : an array with all the smaller numbers stored.
//mex() : "minimal excludant" - the smallest non-negative integer not in array
int grundyNum(int state)
{
    if(visited[state])
        return grundy[state];
    int grundArr[wordStates.size()];
    int loc =0;
    visited[state] = true;
    for(int xx =0;xx<wordStates.size();xx++)
    {
        if((state&wordStates[xx]) == wordStates[xx])
        {
            grundArr[loc] = grundyNum(state^wordStates[xx]);
            loc++;
        }
    }
    grundy[state] =  mex(grundArr,loc);
    return grundy[state];
}
```

Simply calling the function with the following gives the winner :

```
result = grundy(1111111);
winner = result==0?"B":"A";
```